# why is my default @RequestMapping automaticlly selected?

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, saml

I have two @RequestMapping that has two different media types produces = "text/html" & produces = "application/json" and only one mapping location both point to  value = "style/inbox".

Why when I do not send a http Accept along with my request does my application/json act as a default ? How to I set this ?

Using Spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping(params = "stillOhh", value = "security/inbox", produces = "text/html")
@ResponseBody
@Nonnull
public String doingSamlHtmlFeed(
        @Nonnull final HttpServletRequest request,
        @Nonnull final HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) @Nonnull final String sId,
        @RequestParam(value = "spid", required = true) @Nonnull final String spId,
        @RequestParam(value = "relays", required = false) @Nullable final String relayS){

        //SOME SECURITY STUFF !!! Saml federation and mapping


    return federated.getContentString();
}


@RequestMapping(params = "something", value = "security/inbox", produces =     
"application/json)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> doingSamlJsonFeed(
        @Nonnull final HttpServletRequest request,
        @Nonnull final HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) @Nonnull final String sId,
        @RequestParam(value = "spid", required = true) @Nonnull final String spId,
        @RequestParam(value = "relays", required = false) @Nullable final      
StringrelayS){

        //SOME SECURITY STUFF !!! Saml federation and mapping

        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(jsonMap, HttpStatus.OK)

        }
```

Comment: Please provide code so that it can be reviwed

Comment: Good point ... its saml federation so I made some pseudo code to explain this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure the default content type. For example if you are using Java config and want `text/html` to be the default content type, you would do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
   }

}
```

Also here is a link containing more detailed information about content negotiation in Spring MVC (the code snippet above is from this article).

http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc